# Create BigInt with a String encoded to base 16

Tags: java, android, biginteger, string-parsing

I am trying to parse a String like this:

f2cff0a43553b2e07b6ae3264bc085a

into a BigInt  however when using the String constructor for BigInt I obviously get a Number format exception:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("f2cff0a43553b2e07b6ae3264bc085a");
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Thanks for your answers sorry it was an easy question, been a long day :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the radix parameter:

`BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("f2cff0a43553b2e07b6ae3264bc085a", 16);`

Answer (score 3):

Just use the constructor with the radix (using 16 as radix):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to specify that the string is in hexadecimal. Try

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("f2cff0a43553b2e07b6ae3264bc085a",16);
```

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/ParsehexadecimalstringtocreateBigInteger.htm
[http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)